# Moving a block in an adaptive

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, adaptive-layout

I make layout from Figma [Webovio](https://www.figma.com/file/2rdy1qjBTl7D6BAC8S4qlf/Webovio?node-id=0%3A2)

Made the following code

```css
/* =================================================================== */

.techno-articles {
  margin-top: 104px;
}

.techno-articles__container {}

.techno__block_container {}

.techno-articles__items {}

.techno-article__item {}

.item__techno-article {}

.item__techno-article_example {}

.item__techno-article_content {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;*/
}

@media (max-width: 696px) {
  .item__techno-article_content {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .item__techno-article_image {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
  .item__techno-article_body {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

.item__techno-article_image {
  flex: 0 0 calc(735/1441*100%);
  /*calc(735/1441*100%)*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 0px calc(550/1441*100%) 0px;
}

.item__techno-article_image img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.item__techno-article_body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: calc(96/1441*100vw);
  /*136*/
  padding-right: calc(133/1441*100vw);
  /*110*/
}

.item__techno-article_title {
  color: rgba(77, 83, 60, 1);
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 48px;
  /* or 133% */
  color: #4D533C;
}

.item__techno-article_text {
  padding-top: 24px;
  color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  /* or 162% */
  color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
}

.item__techno-article_link {
  color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
}

.item__techno-article_comment {
  color: #4D533C;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 50px 50px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.145947);
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 400;
  margin: -158px calc(664/1441*100vw) 0px calc(323/1441*100vw);
  /*604*/
  width: calc(453/1441*100vw);
}

.item__techno-article_comment_ownership {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.item__techno-article_comment_author_image {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.item__techno-article_comment_text {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 33px;
}

.item__techno-article_comment_author {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.item__techno-article_comment_author_position {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  /* identical to box height */
  color: #152934;
}

.item__techno-article_text>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}

.item__techno-article_link {
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:regular,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Webovio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="techno-articles">
    <div class="techno-articles__container techno__block_container">
      <div class="techno-articles__items">
        <div class="techno-article__item item__techno-article">
          <div class="item__techno-article_example">
            <div class="item__techno-article_content">
              <div class="item__techno-article_image">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoO67.png" alt="technoDVD">
              </div>
              <div class="item__techno-article_body">
                <div class="item__techno-article_title">The wall new Balenciaga.com</div>
                <div class="item__techno-article_text">
                  <p class="first__p">This article is floated online with an aim to help you find the best dvd printing solution.</p>
                  <p class="second__p">Dvd printing is an important feature used by large and small DVD production houses to print information on DVDs.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item__techno-article_link">See Case Study</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item__techno-article_comment">
              <div class="item__techno-article_comment_text">
                “In my history of working with trade show vendors, I can honestly say that there is not one company that I've ever worked with that has better service than Exhibit Systems.”
              </div>
              <div class="item__techno-article_comment_ownership">
                <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author_image">
                  <img src="img/authors/author1.png" alt="Author comment">
                </div>
                <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author_info">
                  <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author">Angel Armstrong</div>
                  <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author_position">Founder & CEO, Google</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

As a result, I get the following window for tablets

[image: Windowfortablet]

As you can see, the image did not occupy 100% of the block, despite the following styles

```
.item__techno-article_content {
    display: flex;
    /*flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;*/
}

@media (max-width: 696px) {
    .item__techno-article_content {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .item__techno-article_image {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
    }
    .item__techno-article_body {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}

.item__techno-article_image {
    flex: 0 0 calc(735/1441*100%); /*calc(735/1441*100%)*/
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 0px calc(550/1441*100%) 0px;    
}

.item__techno-article_image img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.item__techno-article_body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: calc(96/1441*100vw); /*136*/
    padding-right: calc(133/1441*100vw); /*110*/
}
.item__techno-article_title {
    color: rgba(77, 83, 60, 1);

    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 48px;
    /* or 133% */


    color: #4D533C;
}
.item__techno-article_text {
    padding-top: 24px;
    color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    /* or 162% */
    
    color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);    
}
```

Tell me how to achieve the display of the last picture and block of text at 100% width with an adaptive decrease in the size of the browser window.

I want to make an adaptive. I want to know the causes of my code not working and how to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

So because your code is fine until it reaches a mobile device I would target your media queries in this instance. You can use `min-width: 100%;` on `.item__techno-article_image`. Then use  `width: 100%;` and `margin: 0;` on `.item__techno-article_comment`.

```css
/* =================================================================== */

.techno-articles {
  margin-top: 104px;
}

.techno-articles__container {}

.techno__block_container {}

.techno-articles__items {}

.techno-article__item {}

.item__techno-article {}

.item__techno-article_example {}

.item__techno-article_content {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;*/
}

@media (max-width: 696px) {
  .item__techno-article_content {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .item__techno-article_image {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  .item__techno-article_body {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .item__techno-article_comment {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
@media (min-width: 696px) {
  .item__techno-article_comment {
    margin: -158px calc(664/1441*100vw) 0px calc(323/1441*100vw);
    /*604*/
    width: calc(453/1441*100vw);
  }
}
  .item__techno-article_image {
    flex: 0 0 calc(735/1441*100%);
    /*calc(735/1441*100%)*/
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 0px calc(550/1441*100%) 0px;
  }
  .item__techno-article_image img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .item__techno-article_body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: calc(96/1441*100vw);
    /*136*/
    padding-right: calc(133/1441*100vw);
    /*110*/
  }
  .item__techno-article_title {
    color: rgba(77, 83, 60, 1);
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 48px;
    /* or 133% */
    color: #4D533C;
  }
  .item__techno-article_text {
    padding-top: 24px;
    color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    /* or 162% */
    color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
  }
  .item__techno-article_link {
    color: rgba(33, 56, 66, 0.6);
  }
  .item__techno-article_comment {
    color: #4D533C;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 50px 50px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.145947);
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 400;
  }
  .item__techno-article_comment_ownership {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .item__techno-article_comment_author_image {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
  }
  .item__techno-article_comment_text {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 33px;
  }
  .item__techno-article_comment_author {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
  }
  .item__techno-article_comment_author_position {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    /* identical to box height */
    color: #152934;
  }
  .item__techno-article_text>*:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 36px;
  }
  .item__techno-article_link {
    margin-top: 90px;
  }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:regular,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Webovio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="techno-articles">
    <div class="techno-articles__container techno__block_container">
      <div class="techno-articles__items">
        <div class="techno-article__item item__techno-article">
          <div class="item__techno-article_example">
            <div class="item__techno-article_content">
              <div class="item__techno-article_image">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoO67.png" alt="technoDVD">
              </div>
              <div class="item__techno-article_body">
                <div class="item__techno-article_title">The wall new Balenciaga.com</div>
                <div class="item__techno-article_text">
                  <p class="first__p">This article is floated online with an aim to help you find the best dvd printing solution.</p>
                  <p class="second__p">Dvd printing is an important feature used by large and small DVD production houses to print information on DVDs.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="item__techno-article_link">See Case Study</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item__techno-article_comment">
              <div class="item__techno-article_comment_text">
                “In my history of working with trade show vendors, I can honestly say that there is not one company that I've ever worked with that has better service than Exhibit Systems.”
              </div>
              <div class="item__techno-article_comment_ownership">
                <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author_image">
                  <img src="img/authors/author1.png" alt="Author comment">
                </div>
                <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author_info">
                  <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author">Angel Armstrong</div>
                  <div class="item__techno-article_comment_author_position">Founder & CEO, Google</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it possible to solve the problem without using `!important`?

Comment: @wfamilyweb Yes, but only if you set your calculated `margin` and `width` on `.item__techno-article_comment` as a `min-width: (696px)` media query.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. Can be replaced   `.item__techno-article_comment { width: 100%!important; margin: 0!important;}` **another command without using `!important`** in my task?

Comment: @wfamilyweb You can see my edits to see what I mean. Refer to the media query and I remove `!important` and added a different query.